# Chrome userscript works on a thread page, but not on a main forum page, with the same structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, userscripts, content-script

So I made a simple Chrome extension that just loads a simple script to remove a specific `.css` file from a forum. The problem is that on a thread page, the script works; but on the main forum page it doesn't.

Here's the script:

```
[...]
//e3 2012/2013
var E3 = document.querySelector('#website-specials');
E3.remove();
//var cssE3 = document.querySelectorAll('[href="http://website/e3/2013/css/styles.css"]')[0];
//cssE3.remove(); works too
alert('debug: removed');
[...]
```

Relevant `manifest.json` bits:

```
"matches": ["*://*.website.com/*"]
...

"js": ["jquery-2.0.1.min.js", "my_script.js"]
```

It **Works** (removes the CSS) on [this **thread page**](http://website.com/_t_2474855).

It **Doesn't work** (CSS remains) on [this **main page**](http://website.com/_f_57).

I hope I'm not missing something simple.

Comment: What about debugging? Is the CSS file named the same?

Comment: According to the page source code it's the exact same css link

Comment: All I can think of right now is that the element you are trying to find is not yet loaded... Although, I am not sure how to test this.

Comment: Weird, if I use the same code on a user.js or javascript console (like this one https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/javascript-console/ohpmcainjdkbnkmkfmfbadfljaogedna/related) instead of loading the .js file inside my addon it does work.

Comment: I do not know much about userscripts but can you use $(document).ready lol :D

Comment: @GEMI, `$(document).ready()` is NA here.  Userscripts and Greasemonkey scripts (and content scripts) fire at, or after, `$(document).ready()` by default.

Answer (score 1):

[Adblock Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/empty-title/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb) is perfect for this kind of thing.  Rather than trying a userscript or extension to block an external file, just install Adblock Plus and then add a filter for `http://website.com/e3/2013/css/styles.css`.

---

If you insist on a userscript approach, then it appears that your existing code is fighting a **race condition**.  That `<link>` node is part of a document that is stored in a div and is apparently manipulated by javascript (AJAX).  Sometimes your script fires in time to catch a copy and sometimes it doesn't.  This is exacerbated by the fact that [Chrome scripts fire at unpredictable times, by default](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#run_at).

It *might* be sufficient just to add [`"run_at": "document_end"`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#run_at) to your manifest.json. (Which ironically, fires *before* the default script execution time.)

However, to be sure, use an interval and also delete all copies of that link.  Like so:

```
var cssChkInterval = setInterval (killBadCSS, 222);

function killBadCSS (x) {
    var cssE3 = document.querySelectorAll (
        'link[href="http://website.com/e3/2013/css/styles.css"]'
    );
    if (cssE3.length) {
        for (var J = cssE3.length - 1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
            cssE3[J].remove ();
        }

        clearInterval (cssChkInterval);
    }
}
```

---

---

Or, since you are loading jQuery, Use it! :

```
var cssChkInterval = setInterval (killBadCSS, 222);

function killBadCSS (x) {
    var cssE3 = $('link[href="http://website.com/e3/2013/css/styles.css"]');
    if (cssE3.length) {
        cssE3.remove ();

        clearInterval (cssChkInterval);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm even using your methods the css remains in the main page, thanks for the reply anyways.

Comment: I tested my answer before posting and I just retested it.  Adblock Plus works.  The First userscript Works.  The jQuery code also works.  That's *three* solutions and they all work.  If it doesn't work for you, provide: (1) The error messages on the console, (2) The exact URL, if different from above.  (3) Your system parameters/specifications -- including what other extensions you are running, (4) the **exact, unedited, complete** source of the extension code you tried. Anything else that you are doing or that is going on. (5) Try it logged in verses un-logged in.